# SQL Server stored procedure - get table name from table to use in query without using dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where my database tables all have a certain GUID after the table name, and each time there is an update/upgrade, the GUID changes. As such, this creates a complication with stored procedures as I would have to get the current GUID (from a table it's stored in) at the beginning of the stored proc and append it to the table name in order to query it. I would really really like to avoid dynamic sql for all the reasons known to most of us. Is there any way around this without dynamic sql?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like a *horrible* implementation. You're asking how to reference a table's name by not using its name....?

Comment: You cannot dynamic reference an object without dynamic SQL. If you don't want dynamic SQL, fix your design. Let's not even get onto the fact that because of this design you most certainly have no referential integrity either. You have a long road ahead of you, but one you must travel.

Comment: I suppose you could also implement a view to provide a consistent name for a table, changing the view when the base table is renamed, but *not* renaming tables would be the proper way

Comment: Being [afraid of dynamic SQL](https://sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql) is no way to live, especially when you design a system that absolutely begs for it. Imagine not using bleach ever because someone drank some once. Rotating a view or a synonym could help but this sounds like the foundation of a really brittle system.

Comment: @AaronBertrand A better parable is: keep bleach away from children. Children getting poisoned by bleach happens pretty regularly.

Comment: Guys, do you really think I came up with this? I have no control whatsoever over this system. I am just having to work with it and join to it from an external database so my hands are tied. I am asking for a solution to the situation I'm in, whether I like it or not.

Comment: @user11889334 And we're all trying to help you solve the problem, don't take things as personal criticism (and you can't expect us to know from the question that you don't have any say over the existing design - all you say is you don't want to use dynamic SQL).

Comment: @Aaron - Lol I'm not taking anything personally. I'm just explaining why telling me WHY it's a bad solution isn't really resolving the issue. I absolutely appreciate everyone's input

Comment: To be fair, a lot of people posting questions here don't know their solution is bad but _do_ have control over it so can fix it. If an old lady brought her car into the mechanic to fix a tail light and they had a flat tire, should you tell her about the flat tire or nah? Sometimes the more important fix is a side effect of the thing you wanted to fix.

Answer (score 4):

One method is to create a synonym with a constant name for use in the stored procedure and recreate the synonym whenever a new table is created.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.GetFoo
AS
SELECT Col1 FROM Bar;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Bar-3BFBBE1D-AB03-4F08-AE20-F58F86E79685](Col1 int)
GO
DROP SYNONYM IF EXISTS dbo.Bar;
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.Bar FOR dbo.[Bar-3BFBBE1D-AB03-4F08-AE20-F58F86E79685];
GO
EXEC dbo.GetFoo;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Bar-BDB462D8-FF8E-4009-A756-71D7B4CE3D07](Col1 int)
GO
DROP SYNONYM IF EXISTS dbo.Bar;
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.Bar FOR dbo.[Bar-3BFBBE1D-AB03-4F08-AE20-F58F86E79685];
GO
EXEC dbo.GetFoo;
GO
```

Comment: So, how long until the OP asks how they can dynamically create/alter all these synonyms? ;)

Comment: For safety's sake I'd probably throw in an `sp_recompile` of the stored procedure, even though this should happen automatically as a result of recreating the synonym, and even if we're "sure" the structure of the underlying table will "never change". I've seen too many mysterious failures with such setups.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern about dynamic SQL is misplaced.

Since your table name is stored in a table, and hopefully it's a `uniqueidentifier` type, and this isn't coming from user input, what is the problem with this approach? Where do you see any danger?

```
DECLARE @tablename sysname, @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @tablename = QUOTENAME(GUIDcolumn)
  FROM dbo.BrittleTable; -- WHERE ...

SET @sql = N'SELECT whatever FROM ' + @tablename ...;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

If it's not a uniqueidentifier type (why isn't it?), and you're worried someone could shove something else in this column, then you can do this:

```
DECLARE @tablename sysname, @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @tablename = QUOTENAME(GUIDcolumn)
  FROM dbo.BrittleTable
  WHERE TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, GUIDcolumn) IS NOT NULL;

IF @tablename IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @sql = N'SELECT whatever FROM ' + @tablename ...;
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

The presence of dynamic SQL does not equal the presence of danger. Like anything, it can be misused, but it can also be used responsibly with great success and zero risk. I've put together a rebuttal for claims of "we don't want to use dynamic SQL because we've heard stories" here:

- [Dynamic SQL](https://sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql)

But the most important ones to read are these two tips:

- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-1/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: I agree that it isn't dangerous in this situation. However I believe that the query execution is not as efficient when using dynamic sql. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @user11889334 That is not true at all. Query execution has very little to do with how the query text was originally constructed. If you've read that somewhere, please point it out, so we can correct them. If you haven't read that anywhere, don't make things up or invent imaginary obstacles to the best solutions. :-) (But also, listen to people when they question your original design that creates the problem, making you need a solution in the first place.)